# login_destination module and link with anchor

Tags: navigation

I want to to use login_destination module to have a link to login screen in comment-wrapper.tpl.php, so after the login, the user came back to write the comment.

I have installed and configured login_destination and modified comment-wrapper.tpl.php.

The login_destination documentation say that if I use my own links to the login screen, i have to use GET to supply "current" parameter.

So in my theme I've added to comment-wrapper.tpl.php:

```
$destino = drupal_get_destination();
$destino = $destino['destination'];
```

And changed the text to add the link to the login screen:

```
<?php if ($comment_form): ?>
<h2 class="title comment-form"><?php print t('<a href="@login">Login</a> or anonymous comment:', array('@login' => url('user', array('query' => array('current' => $destino), 'fragment' => 'comments')))) ?></h2>
<?php print $comment_form; ?>
```

Now, when I click on "Login" link, opens an url like:

```
SITE.com/user?current=node/3#comments
```

But after finish the login, I'm redirected to node/3 alias, without the anchor #comments.

If I type on the browser the url:

```
SITE.com/node/3#comments
```

It' works ok, it goes to the #comments anchor.

Any help or suggerence?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?php if ($comment_form): ?>
        <h2 class="title comment-form"><?php l('Login or anonymous comment', user, array('query' => 'current=node/3#comments')); ?></h2>
<?php print $comment_form; ?>
```

Comment: I've tried with: <h2 class="title comment-form"><?php print l(t('login or anonymous comment'),'user', array('query' => 'current=node/3#comments')); ?></h2>  But it gives me an error: Recoverable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to drupal_http_build_query() must be an array, string given, called in /var...  I think its because your code is for drupal 6 and I'm with drupal 7.  I have tried these: <h2 class="title comment-form"><?php print l(t('login'),'user', array('attributes' => array('query' => array('current' => 'node/3#comments')))); ?></h2>  but then the link just points to: 'user' :-?

Comment: Try your code like this <h2 class="title comment-form"><?php print l(t('login'),'user', array('attributes' => array('query' => 'current=node/3#comments'))); ?></h2>

Comment: I've tried, but with this code the link in "user" points just to SITE.COM/user. Without the anchor and the query...

Answer (score 0):

Update: 
after reading your quesiton again, it seems that redirecting to a fragment is not possible with destination or current parameters. See [this](http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/login_destination/login_destination.module/function/login_destination_perform_redirect/7)
Here is my previous answer where I assumed the problem was in the l() function.

Just have a look at

```
<?php if ($comment_form): ?>
<h2 class="title comment-form">
<?php print t('!login or anonymous comment:', 
        array('!login' => l(t('Login'), 'user/login', array(
          'query' => array('current' => $destino), 
          'fragment' => 'comments')))); ?></h2>
<?php print $comment_form; ?>
```

A few points: I have used !login in the t() function. if you use @login, it will not be parsed as HTML. Instead, you will see the a tag in plain text.

l() function accepts the actual text of the A tag. We need to use t() function here.

I just tested it myself and worked for me.